# How do I make nested mixins flat in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, mixins

How to correct this?
Typescript says `'(Anonymous class)' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own base expression.` now.

```js
type Ctor = (new(...arg) => any) | null
type Mixin = <B extends Ctor, D extends B> (C: B) => D

const mix = <B extends Ctor> (Base: B, ...mixins: Mixin[]) =>
    class extends (
        mixins.length ? mix(mixins[0](Base), ...mixins.slice(1)) : Base
    ) {}
```

Thanks.